# Is it possible to buffer data within a variable in python while the rest of the script is running?

Tags: python, buffer, lidar

I am using a Lidar (360 degree sensor which measures distance and angle) sensor for the localization of a vessel. The problem is that I make several calculations with this data which is the cause of the python script to crash. The reason is that when the script is not listening to the data of the sensor for a long period it crashes. I solved this by reading out the sensor data in another python file and writing it to a txt file. In the file with my calculations I read this txt file and this solves it, but I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this. If it is possible to use a variable that can be used as buffer while the rest of the script keeps running?

Kind regards

Comment: look into try except statements, https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=python+try   you can run some code, catch the errors without crashing your interpreter

Comment: And, probably, try to use multithreading.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code is not really relevant. Cause it's just a for loop that reads the data from the sensor, but the block of code inside the for loop takes too long for the likings of the sensor which causes the Lidar sesnor to crash. I'll look into multithreading. Cause try and except is something we've already tried.